# Beginner lens for Nikon D3200

Tags: nikon-d3200

Which lens is good for beginner with Nikon D3200? Is there any other better lens to replace combo kit or should I stick with the combo kit only?

Answer (score -1):

You may start with a Zoom one like [55-200mm](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/camera-lenses/af-s-dx-zoom-nikkor-55-200mm-f%252f4-5.6g-ed.html) or a Prime lens like [35mm](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/camera-lenses/af-s-dx-nikkor-35mm-f1.8g.html)

one of these could be a good start.

Comment: Could you explain why either of these lenses might be a good idea?